# Setting expiry time of cookie in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I need to set a cookie which expires after 4 hours. Now, the users can reside in multiple timezones. So, if I set the cookie in rails and set expiry based on server time, would it lead to invalid expiry times for some users or does rails handle this issue or does browser cookies themselves handle this issue ? Should I set this cookie in javascript, so that user's  browser time is taken to set the expiry?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `invalid expiry times for some users`? What is use case?

Comment: I need the cookie to expire after 4 hours of setting it. If the timezone of server is not same as user and I set the cookie on server, then it may expire at different time than 4 hours for a user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to expire cookie after 4 hours since it was set. You just need to specify time that should be ahead of 4 hours from current time. There is no concern with timezone. Because 4 hours is same for all timezones :P

```
cookies[:login] = { value: "XJ-122", expires: 4.hour.from_now }
```

[**Source**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html)

Comment: But, cookies are stored on browser and browser's timezone can be different than server. 4 hours as calculated at server might not be same for a browser in different timezone.

Comment: Can you shared how you are implementing cookie expiration on client browser? It will be helpful to explain the logic

Comment: @shreyj The difference of timezones between the server and the browser does not matter because the server will send an expiration date which includes a timezone (its own or UTC/GMT probably). Said differently, the expiration date is an absolute time that is not ambiguous to the browser. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie for an example.